# Can Tomcat Manager be run safely on an alternative path?

Tags: apache, security, tomcat, tomcat7, web-deployment

I currently have web servers running Apache Tomcat 7 with the Tomcat Manager application configured at the default path of http://{server.name}:8080/manager/.  The Manager is of course secured with a strong randomly generated password, so I am not worried about any script kiddies getting access.  But script kiddies do try frequently to get access, causing hundreds on annoying lines like this in my catalina.out logs:

```
Dec 15, 2013 9:24:53 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"
Dec 15, 2013 9:24:53 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "tomcat"
Dec 15, 2013 9:24:54 AM org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm authenticate
WARNING: An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"
.....
```

This can be a bother when I am actually trying to use the logs to debug something.

I wondered if I could move the Tomcat Manager path to a different port or just a different path to avoid this nonsense, so I tried doing just that.  I copied the application from $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/**manager** to something like $CATALINA_BASE/webapps/**iuhqtrhuirehpiugerhupgareiup**.  I found that I could use http://{server.name}:8080/iuhqtrhuirehpiugerhupgareiup/ successfully.  I could even undeploy the old manager app from the new one.  All appears fine.

Before I update my deployment scripts and try this on a production server, however, I want to be sure that nothing might break.  Is there anything to watch out for with this approach?  Does the Tomcat Manager have any hardcoded "manager" strings that might cause it to break in unexpected or rare ways?  Is anyone else doing this?

I realize this is more obscurity than security, but if it keeps the script kiddies from cluttering up my logs, I'm okay with that.  (I'm still using strong passwords.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have tried running this for the past couple months with no problems, so yes, it does appear to be perfectly safe to rename the manager application.  I have noticed a significant decline in hack attempts in my logs as a result; there is rarely more than one connection to the default manager path on each attempt.  I suspect script kiddies assume Tomcat is not running if the manager is not at the default path.